# ALSA compatibility layer

Tags: linux, audio, alsa

I have written a driver that takes audio streams and processes the data. No sound is output by design (it is stored and processed).

But now I have a requirement to provide access for applications that natively use ALSA to use my driver.

Has anyone else done this? Does anyone know of an ALSA compatibility layer or a way to provide this without using a full ALSA installation?

Comment: Really, you would just have to provide your own binary-compatible implementation of libasound.  This may not be simple.

Comment: @TourosSpoon Why not implement your driver as an ALSA driver?  See http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/sound/alsa/.

Comment: @Peter L I don't need all the capabilities of ALSA and the driver is already developed. It would be inefficient to implement ALSA just to provide connectivity to the work I have already done.

Comment: @TourosSpoon Ah, in that case perhaps you could take an existing ALSA driver and use it as a stub interface to your own driver.  Creating an ALSA compatibility layer higher up, like in user land, sounds like more of a headache.  Also take a look at the PulseAudio interface.

Comment: @Peter L - thanks for the suggestion. Regarding PulseAudio, I am trying to reduce the amount of code between audio applications and my driver, not add layers. But again, thanks for the suggestion.